# RewriteEngine URL to php _get arguments

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my website I want to internally execute a url like `mydomain.com/dir/test` as `mydomain.com/dir/process.php?arg=test`

I already created a htaccess file within the folder "dir", and when I try to access `mydomain.com/dir/test`, it displays the page of `process.php`, but when I try to access `$_GET["arg"]`, it does not contain the string `test` but the string `process.php`.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ process.php?arg=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for your result is a rewriting loop. You try to stop the rewriting process by using the `[L]` flag, but as many others you miss understand what that flag actually does. It does *not* end the rewriting process, but only the current run of that process. In your case the rewriting process starts another run and *again* rewrites your already rewritten request. In the second run the pattern `^(.*)$` matches what you have rewritten to in the first run, that explains your outcome.

You have two options to solve this.

1) use a condition to prevent the second rewriting run:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQEUEST_URI} !/process\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ process.php?arg=$1 [L]
```

2) use the `END` flag which is provided by newer versions of the apache http server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ process.php?arg=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using that second rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).